# Will putting de-icer spray in the washer bottle remove ice from my windscreen?

Tags: windshield-washer, ice

I have no screenwash, and my water in the washer bottle keeps freezing up, and I can't get to the shops for a few days.

[image]

It says nothing about the ingredients, but it says it has "Bitrex" for protection...

It smells very alcoholly and bitter, if that helps.

I don't have heated jets or anything, but I do have mist jets. Will it actually defrost my windscreen as well? The bottle is about 2L.

**Can I put this into the washer bottle?**

**Will it have any effect on ice?**

Comment: It contains 5% Aliphatic Hydrocarbons.  I believe those would evaporate in your windshield wiper reservoir

Comment: Note that Bitrex is not an active ingredient, and is only added because it's "the most bitter chemical known to man".  Its a deterrent to stop little kids or animals from messing with or eating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Data sheet I viewed on line it should do no harm. How effective it will be, will depend on how much it is diluted by the water in the washer tank. The formula may also evaporate quickly in the tank. In short it is better than straight water, but likely not as effective as a product designed to be added directly to the windscreen washer tank.

Answer (score 1):

Try metholated spirits. that should do the trick.

Comment: In setting your car on fire.